# angular-cli to universal-cli [Angular2]

Tags: angular, angular-cli, universal, universal-cli

In existing angular-cli project I am trying to integrate universal...

I follwed guide from here: https://github.com/devCrossNet/universal-cli

But after I do `ung serve` I get error:

```
/home/master/Documents/foo/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_adapter.js:9
export function getDOM() {
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/master/Documents/foo/dist/server/server.bundle.js:1375:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/master/Documents/foo/dist/server/server.bundle.js:21:30)
```

Anyone know what is a problem?

Comment: You need to use 'isBrowser' - import { isBrowser, isNode } from 'angular2-universal'

Comment: @Vladimir, have you solved this issue? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @Vladimir - found a work around: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/287#issuecomment-268190709 - check out orgbx's reply.